# How I get access to new intervals using "getNextDataRange()" of Selection Class?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm facing an error when I try to get values using the Method "getNextDataRange(Direction)" but I can't understand where I missed out.

first: I Opened another spreadsheet and selected the first sheet. I SET "B2" as initial current cell. Then I back to select the actual sheet to get access of "Selection" Class, so finally I can use "getNextDataRange":
Heres my code:

```
function ok() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID").getSheets()

  var firstsheet = sheets[0].getRange("B2").activateAsCurrentCell().getSheet().getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.RIGHT).getValues

  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B1").activate().setValue(firstsheet[0][0])
}
```

--
3. Then I wanna bring the values obtained in the range select by the getNextDataRange to import to my actual spreadsheet. Start from the range "B1" and taking the first line and the first column of the selection that I got previously.

The fallow error occours:

```
Cannot find getNextDataRange ((class)) method.
```

Someone has already faced that? I appreciate if someone could explain what detail I missed. I believe that is that doubt of many other too.

Comment: I think that the reason of error is `SpreadsheetApp.Direction.RIGHT`. The Enum Direction has 4 properties which are `UP`, `DOWN`, `PREVIOUS` and `NEXT`. There is not property of `RIGHT`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/direction) Please select one of 4 properties and try it again.